# Infopath form error from one computer (.xsn?SaveLocation...)

Tags: xml, sharepoint, infopath

I have a SharePoint site with about 7 InfoPath form templates on it. Clients create new forms from that template and save it onto the site. They then create a workflow for other users to approve.

I started noticing some of Forms were not loading correctly, and no one would approve them. I was able to narrow it down to a single issue in the infopath .xml.

The href parameter in the xml should say something like: (replacing URL with [SharePoint URL] for client privacy)

```
href="http://[SharePoint URL]/InfoPath%20Templates/Payment%20Request.xsn"
```

but instead it says:

```
href="http://[SharePoint URL]/InfoPath%20Templates/Payment%20Request.xsn?SaveLocation=http://[SharePoint URL]/InfoPath%20Forms/&amp;Source=http://[SharePoint URL]/InfoPath%2520Forms/Forms/MyItems.aspx&amp;OpenIn=PreferClient&amp;NoRedirect=true&amp;XsnLocation=http://[SharePoint URL]/InfoPath%20Templates/Payment%20Request.xsn"
```

I was able to narrow this down to a single user on a single machine. If he moves to another machine it stops doing it, and if another user goes to his machine it does not do it.

I have cleared his InfoPath Cache. I have removed the saved InfoPath forms out of the InfoPath application, but I cant seem to find the solution to fix this, without having to erase his profile and create a new one on the machine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. I figured I would post it here just incase google leads another poor sharepoint user, with this problem, to this topic.

There is an Internet Explorer add-on that somehow got disabled on the clients machine. SharepointOpenXMLDocuments.

I have no idea how it got disabled, but once I reenabled it, everything started to work correctly. Who knows the real reason this happened, but here is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and resolved it by going to Advanced Settings in the form library and under Opening Documents in the Browser I set it to Open in the client application.